# issues when Include a php file using short tags

Tags: php, php-shorttags

So, I have 2 PHP files, `index.php` and `include.php`.

In `index.php`

```
<?php
include ('include.php');
?>
```

In `include.php`

```
<?
$a = 1>0;
echo "test";
```

When I run `index.php`, what I get is

```
0; echo "test";
```

This happens when ths include.php is using short open tag, anyone knows what is the problem?

I am using PHP 5.4.16

Comment: Did you enable short tags?

Comment: `short_open_tag = On`

Comment: If you're seeing `0; echo "test";` it means `<?
$a = 1>` is getting parsed as HTML.

Comment: check the short tags setting in your php.ini. I recommend that you don't use short tags because not all server have short tag enabled. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value short_open_tag 1
 </IfModule>
```

or
Set in php.ini

```
short_open_tag = On
```